# Why I am getting this Javascript pop-up window when I tested my system?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

I am a new developer and my Instructor in the university showed me a common security vulnerability in any ASP.NET application. He just created an empty ASP.NET application (.NET Framework 4.0) and after browsing it on the browser using the following link:

```
http://localhost/Test/
```

He just added this part `?--></script><script>alert(37523)</script>` to the end of the link to become:

```
http://localhost/Test/?--></script><script>alert(37523)</script>
```

And by doing this, we got a pop-up window. It is really weird. RequestValidation is enabled by default and it should prevent this. So what should I do to prevent this?

Comment: I think you're talking about `cross side scripting` attack. (Here)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx] a document from microsoft

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but there is nothing useful for solving this issue. This is a kind of Javascript injection to the URL.